# how to add a new Many-To-Many table data using entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

Iam working on an Asp.net mvc web application and entity framework. I have the following table:-

- User table (userID,name,age, etc)
- Group table, (GroupID,name,description,etC)
- and UserGroup table.  (UserID , GroupID)

but since the UserGroup table is a pure many-to-many relationship that stores both UserID & GroupID , so it was not mapped using entity framework. now i know the GroupID and the USerID , so how i can populate the relation between them. should i do something such as :-

```
 Group.Where(a=.a.GroupID).singleordefualt().User.ADD(//something here !!!)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var group = db.Groups.Find(groupId);
if (group != null)
{
    group.Users.Add(user); // add user to existing users
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

OR

```
user.Groups.Add(group); // add group to existing groups
db.SaveChanges();
```

If you want to replace users, then just assign new collection:

```
group.Users = new List<User> { user };
db.SaveChanges();
```

---

If you want to remove user from it's groups and add this user to other group:

```
var user = db.Users.Find(userId);
user.Groups.Clear();
var group = db.Groups.Find(groupId);
user.Groups.Add(group);
db.SaveChanges();
```

---

If you want to remove some users from group:

```
var group = db.Groups.Find(groupId); // get your group
var userToRemove = group.Users.Last(); // select user, e.g. last one
group.Users.Remove(userToRemove); // remove user from group users
db.SaveChanges(); // save changes
```

Comment: but will user inside the "groups.Users.Add(user)" be a new User object, or it should be existing user ?

Comment: @Asp.netmvcAsp.netmvc by default lazy-loading is enabled and all existing users will be loaded when you are accessing users of group. New user will be added to existing users

Comment: but what if i want to assign existing User to the group !!

Comment: @Asp.netmvcAsp.netmvc so what's the problem??!!

Comment: thanks for your reply. But what if i want to remove certain user from certain group. not to remove all users from a group?

Comment: @Asp.netmvcAsp.netmvc added sample for removing some user from group, without removing others